# Select record based on Current hour between hours stored in Sql server 2008 table

Tags: sql

I have table name xyz, in that I have 2 records as below.

```
Record  Prod_available  FromTime   ToTime
1           Pizza       08:00      21:59
2           Beer        22:00      07:59
```

Now I want to select record based on current hour.

Kindly Help me in above case.

Comment: @Rory Jaffe I stored Current hour in one variable ex. 'a' which is INT from current Date time. Then in where clause I wrote  'a' between FromTime and ToTime. But 21:55PM onwards it stops selection of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Retweeted @Gordon Linoff code.

```
    where
(
((FromTime < ToTime) and @time between FromTime and ToTime) or
((FromTime > ToTime) and @time  not between ToTime and  FromTime) -- here swapped the totime and fromtime.
)
```

Comment: Good catch on the order of the operands.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is:

```
where ((FromTime < ToTime) and cast(getdate() as time) between FromTime and ToTime) or
       (FromTime > ToTime and cast(getdate() as time) not between ToTime and EndTime)
      )
```

Comment: for record 2, the example trys to say there criteria is between 22pm to 7.59am next day

Comment: Thanks Gordon for solution, It works fine when time is between 22:00PM to 07:59AM. But when current Time is between 08:00AM and 21:59PM it selects both the records. Kindly help me Gordon

Answer (score 0):

You can try something along these lines:

```
select * from xyz where 
 dateadd (hour, datepart(hour, getdate()), '2000-01-01') between
 dateadd (hour, left(fromtime,2), '2000-01-01') and
 dateadd (hour, case when left(totime,2) < left(fromtime,2) then left(totime,2)+24 else left(totime,2) end, '2000-01-01')
```

Comment: Ray, I will try your solution and will let you know results. Thanks in advance.

Comment: tried solution given by you. It give syntax error near '24 else left(totime,2), '2000-01-01') '  for comma, I am not able to correct it. please help in this case

Comment: Since your time range likely to include next date in the morning, therefore the problem is to compare the time before the date and the time on next date, and my proposed solution is to compose your time value into a virtual date. so that the condition can be compared as a date range